# Android Emulator install debug react native app

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to set up previously working on Mac react native project on Linux and I ran into an issue.

I start the emulator

```
cd $ANDROID_HOME/tools && sudo ./emulator -avd nexus-5X-API-27
```

then I try to install the debug *.apk to it. In the *[project_folder]/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug*

```
sudo adb install -r app-debug.apk
```

and I have the following errors in the adb logcat

```
04-21 10:25:49.672 +0000  1587  1662 D ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [WIFI () - 101] validation passed
04-21 10:25:49.677 +0000  1587  4035 I WifiService: getConnectionInfo uid=10013
04-21 10:25:49.683 +0000  2031  2490 W Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-21 10:25:49.683 +0000  2031  2490 W Conscrypt:   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-21 10:25:49.683 +0000  2031  2490 W Conscrypt:   at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.Platform.setSocketWriteTimeout(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):13)
04-21 10:25:49.683 +0000  2031  2490 W Conscrypt: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: setsockopt failed: EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
04-21 10:25:49.683 +0000  2031  2490 W Conscrypt:   at libcore.io.Linux.setsockoptTimeval(Native Method)
04-21 10:25:49.683 +0000  2031  2490 W Conscrypt:   at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.setsockoptTimeval(ForwardingOs.java:175)
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser : [AppCertManager] IOException while requesting key: 
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser : java.io.IOException: Invalid device key response.
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser :    at gga.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):12)
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser :    at gga.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):64)
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser :    at gfy.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):8)
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser :    at gfu.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):1)
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser :    at gft.a(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):10)
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser :    at com.google.android.gms.auth.account.be.legacy.AuthCronChimeraService.b(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):7)
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser :    at fiw.call(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):3)
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser :    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser :    at nsg.run(:com.google.android.gms@12529024@12.5.29 (040700-192802242):27)
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser :    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser :    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser :    at nya.run(Unknown Source:7)
04-21 10:25:49.746 +0000  2031  2490 W GLSUser :    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
04-21 10:25:54.479 +0000  1587  1600 E memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
```

Any thoughts what could be the cause of that? I would appreciate any direction!

**UPDATE**

Actually, the

```
sudo adb install -r app-debug.apk
```

Installs the app, and everything works. Seems that adb logcat is not relevant here.

However, if I run

```
sudo react-native run-android
```

It executes successfully but on the emulator, I have the following error.

[image]

As far as I understand this error tells that the development server (I assume it's node) returns the error, which means that any changes to the code will not be dynamically picked up, which is what I'm trying to accomplish.

**UPDATE**

OK, I finally figure out what is wrong here.

When I first ran

```
sudo adb install -r app-debug.apk
```

The Running Metro Bundler was not started, meaning after system reboot I hadn't run the

```
sudo react-native run-android
```

Which starts the development server. Therefore the application was running OK.

Now what I did, I killed the server

```
sudo lsof -i :8081 
kill -9 <PID>
```

And started the

```
sudo react-native start
```

In a separate terminal session. There I could see that I have some issues with the watchman lib when I start my app on the emulator, which I believe are the cause of my issue.

Hope it will be useful for somebody.

Comment: LogCat's log is not related to the issue. Could you show terminal log?

Comment: I'm a bit new to the Android, could you be more specific where I can find it?

Comment: sudo adb install -r app-debug.apk   what console shows you when you call it

Comment: @EldarMiensutov thanks! you are correct, it seems to be not related to that. Please see my update I added more details to the issue.